# Netty - How to fetch all frames from DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder to the next handler

Tags: java, sockets, handler, netty

I'm trying to implement a simple Nio socket server by using Netty. My message comes from a gps tracker meitrack's MT90 and i want to split it directly by a comma. So i added a DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder in my channelpipeline before my own handler. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception
{
    ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();

    pipeline.addLast("framer", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(65 * 1024, delimiter));
  //pipeline.addLast("decoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)); 
  //pipeline.addLast("encoder",new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

    pipeline.addLast(new TrackingServerHandler());
}
```

My problem is i don't know how to manage the message splitted in my handler, i just tried to display it on the console but seems like i can access only on the first frame and need to do more stuff to handle all of it.
This is my sample code in my TrackingServerHandler:

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler;

public class TrackingServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>
{
    Charset utf8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf buf) throws Exception
   {
       String message = buf.toString(utf8);
       System.out.println("Message received :\n"+ message);
   }
}
```

Could you help me please? I'm new to Netty.

Answer (score 0):

DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder return only one frame per time. I think you should implement a `MessageToMessageDecoder<GPSData>` and contruct the message by yourself. (Assume the output data is GPSData).

Here is the sample:

```
class MyDecoder extends MessageToMessageDecoder<ByteBuf> {
    protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg, List<Object> out) {
        String something = msg.toString(charset);
        String[] items = something.split(",");
        // Construct GPSData with items
        GPSData data = new GPSData();
        data.latitude = items[0];// whatever
        out.add(data);
    }
}
```

And now you can do something with GPSData:

```
public class TrackingServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<GPSData>
{
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, GPSData data) throws Exception
   {
       // the data is what I want
   }
}
```

DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder is used when the original data are combined with more than one messages(assume the messages seprated by `\n`), eg:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6\n
7,8,9,0,1,2
```